# Angular Routing with CLI

Tags: angular, routes, command-line-interface

Angular Routing is not working. It only works when I put  in index.html

Is the routing i have done is fine or not?
If anyone has example related to angular then please do mail me at saijalshakya1@gmail.com

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';   
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { OurteamComponent } from './ourteam/ourteam.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    OurteamComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
   import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { OurteamComponent } from './ourteam/ourteam.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    OurteamComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<h1>saijal shakya</h1>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**ourteam.component.html**

```
<p>
  ourteam works!
</p>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Sxc</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which version of angular you are using ?

Comment: @rohankangale i am using the latest one

Answer (score 0):

You have not used the AppRoutingModule in the imports for app.module.ts.
It is required in there for sure. 
Also, your app.routing.module.ts is same as the app.module.ts which is not correct.

Use the app.routing.module.ts file for defining the mapping of the routes and its components.